# Can't manage video card with Nvidia drivers version 510 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed NVIDIA drivers version 510.60.02.

[image]

but then I started getting weird errors when trying to use the settings app or try to change anything on the configuration thorough the terminal.

The app just says that it can't change anything. Here is an example where in the bottom left corner it just says "Failed to set new Fan Speed!" when I try to change the fan speeds:

[image]

The equivalent in the terminal is a weird error that doesn't say anything informative:

```
ERROR: Error assigning value 70 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed'
       (systemName:0[fan:1]) as specified in assignment
       '[fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=70' (Unknown Error).
```

I can use `nvidia-smi` but not `nvidia-settings`.
When I try using `nvidia-settings` I get the following:

```
(nvidia-settings:10514): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 08:55:59.436: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 08:55:59.529: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 08:55:59.529: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I am fighting this since yesterday and an out of options right now, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Can think about anything more than trying to perform clean install which I did a few times with some different approaches I found in the Internet.

Now am about to check if I have secured boot enabled in my bios but I doubt that this is the case.

And finally will revert to version 470 as it used to work. But I want the 510 because it enables full mining capabilities for the card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this.

It's because Xorg is not running in root mode.

This is what I did to make it work:

1. **sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf**
2. Uncomment the "WaylandEnable" line and make sure it says "**WaylandEnable=false**"
3. **sudo vi /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config**
4. Add "**needs_root_rights = yes**" to the end of the file
5. Reboot

See the following for more info:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Overclocking_not_working_with_Unknown_Error
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg#Rootless_Xorg

Comment: Absolute lifesaver. Worked like a charm and somehow I didn't manage to find these references being searching for like 2-3 days now in a row for this error.